# How to make multiple calls from one sip account to multi sip accounts?

Tags: objective-c, ios, sip, voip, pjsip

I don't have experience in pjsip. Now I want coding a feature in iPhone like this: from my sip number I make multiple calls to group of sip numbers. If anyone accepts call, the others are denied. I'm using pjsip library to develop my app in iPhone.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

pjsip does allow to make multiple calls from same account. It is limited by this *PJSUA_MAX_CALLS*

Go through simple_pjsua.c. It does provide a good example of exactly what you have asked.

Here you will find *'on_call_state*, this callback is called whenever call state is changed. Typically whenever a call is answered call state will transition to *PJSIP_INV_STATE_CONNECTING/PJSIP_INV_STATE_CONFIRMED* as 200OK/ACK is received/sent.

To make a call look for *pjsua_call_make_call*

Good luck!!

Comment: I used pjsua_call_make_call to call another number while one call is already going on but it returns me status code 70010. How can I place a call while one call is already going on. This I want to implement call conference with pjsip. Thank you very much for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at pjsua_app_cli.c in function cmd_make_multi_call.

```
for (i=0; i<count; ++i) {
pj_status_t status;

status = pjsua_call_make_call(current_acc, &tmp, &call_opt, NULL,
    NULL, NULL);
if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
    break;
}
```

Hope it helps!